# iOS: Couldn't link HTML string loaded from sqlite db with images in bundl

Tags: iphone, html, ios, image, uiwebview

How to link HTML string loaded from sqlite db with images stored in bundle

```
[self.wbvuContents loadHTMLString:self.page baseURL:nil];
```

self.page may be as the following:

```
<html>
<body>
<div  style='margin:20 0 0 0px'>  <img style=' ' alt='' height='48' src='images/01-01-018.jpg' width='75' /> 
</body>
</html>
```

and 01-01-018.jpg image is added to the bundle

when use the above code images not appeared in webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *path;
NSURL *baseURL;
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
myBaseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

[self.wbvuContents loadHTMLString:self.page baseURL:myBaseURL];
```

then, if your image 01-01-018.jpg is in your bundle :

```
<html>
<body>
<div  style='margin:20 0 0 0px'>  <img style=' ' alt='' height='48' src='01-01-018.jpg' width='75' /> 
</body>
</html>
```